# Simple iPhone accelerometer ball-maze game

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, maze

I want to make a simple 2D game where the user has to navigate a ball through a maze (using the accelerometer of course). I used a simple view to make use of the accelerometer and move a ball on the screen. Now how do I go about building the maze? Would I have to use cocos2d or something similar? How do I make the ball stop or rebound when it hits the wall of the maze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this game... it does a great job with the accelerometer and also setting boundaries.

http://github.com/haqu/tweejump

Answer (score 0):

This one is for Android rather than iPhone, but it has some parts that are very relevant to your project, such as moving a ball. Does not include ball rebounding or building a random maze; it loads mazes from a file.

- [Amazed](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Amazed)

For ball/wall bouncing, try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845033/bouncing-a-ball-off-a-surface).

For generating a maze, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502/whats-a-good-algorithm-to-generate-a-maze).